# Apache Server File Permission

Tags: ajax, apache, tomcat6

I am using Apache Tomcat 6.0 & I am getting 403 Forbidden error from the server while making a   ajax put request to the server .

Can Anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

- Use POST instead of put
- Make sure the target page is not protected by username/password
- Also apache can restrict access to files based on other criteria, like IP

Comment: I have to update a file directly using Ajax put request , Is that also possible by Post request? Please let me know if Possible. Thanks